# Building Software for handling Database in Java

Tags: java, database

I want to develop a software for a book rental store which is to have the following specifications:

- The store has a large collection of books.
- A person can become a member by depositing a certain amount and filling up his details. At any point, a member can cancel his membership and take back his deposit, if he has no dues out-standing against him.
- Whenever the store purchases a new item, its details such as date of procurement, price and daily rental charge are entered. After passage of a year, the daily rental charge is automatically halved.
- A member can rent at most 2 books at a time. The details are entered by a store clerk and a receipt indicating the daily rental charge is printed.
- Whenever a member returns his rented item, the amount to be paid is displayed. After the amount is paid, the items are marked returned.

I am a beginner in Java and have no prior experience of such Database Management. What would be the best way to make such a software in Java? A detailed approach will be helpful.

**Edit:** I am comfortable with working with IDEs such as Eclipse & Netbeans and have reasonable experience in basic Java programming. However I have no clue regarding which API/plug-in/etc. to go after for the above mentioned application. So, what precisely I am looking after is how to get started with developing this software.

Comment: Hey we all want help, but you should be more specific + show some effort , &where you are . maybe pursue  a path, then come back w/ specific problem

Comment: As it stands, we have a specification of which *many* options exist afterward

Comment: Start with learning [`JDBC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).  Though you might wind up using more advanced APIs, it's always a good idea to start with basics.

Answer (score 1):

**Step One**

Download the software you need.

- A development environment (IDE). I suggest NetBeans or Eclipse, as they are both beginner friendly and free. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html) is one such download of Java with NetBeans.
- A database management software. I recommend SQLExpress for beginners. You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx#Installation_Options). Also free.

**Step Two**

Populate your database with tables and data. If you don't know much about databases, you are going to have to spend a few days learning the basics. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB) is a video course that appears to be popular, but I suggest searching for a course that engages you and helps you learn best.

**Step Four**

Create your Java class and import the packages you need.

- `import java.sql.*;`

**Step Five**

Open a connection, query, close the connection, and then process your results.

```
Connection conn;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
    System.out.println("connected");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(conn != null) {
    conn.open();
    // Create a statement
    // Run the statement and get results
    conn.close();
    for(Result r: resultSet) {
       // Do what you want with the results
    }
}
```

Notice I skipped step three. There is some setup required for SQLExpress to work with JDBC that I cannot recall. I DO recall Googling every error I hit and finding precise answers, but if anyone has a neat list, edit this.